# How to send video on remote web server using Raspberry Pi and camera module?

Tags: pi-3

I want to create an IoT device that capture the video and send it to a remote web server via Internet. I don't want to create a webserver inside raspberry pi and access it in other devices like smart phones but rather the Pi based IoT device should send the video to remote server i.e. AWS or any other server and than allow users to access video from these server via App. So how to achieve it? Many tutorials like [this](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/video-streaming-with-raspberry-pi-camera/) describe a method of creating a web server inside raspberry pi to access video, but I don't want to use this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python and HTTP POST for non-live stream , you can see an example of python code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script). But many other solutions exists with another protocols or languages.